# How to fix? Android Studio file path Error

Tags: android, dictionary, exception

I get such an error when doing sdk setup. I need to use file name with `ASCII` character. But how can I change this path?
Screenshot of thst?
[image: Screenshot of thst]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the path of your SDK, it cannot be inside your Users/kullan... folder because of the non-ASCII characters in your User's name.

Here's a [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) of all the accepted ASCII characters

Comment: How do I change the path to the SDK?